# Is it possible to programmatically set instance attributes?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to initialize 50 variables in a Python class. I'd like to do this by loading a dict where each key/value pair corresponds to a `self.key = value` statement, which are all initialized to None by default.

The code I have right now is:

```
    def load_values(self, values):
        for k, v in values.iteritems():  
            if k in self.__dict__.keys(): # if the key in the dict matches a previously
                                          # initialized attribute
                self.k = v
```

This doesn't work because Python thinks `k` is the name of an attribute, which it is not. How can I make this work? I am running Python 2.7.

Comment: You use `setattr(self, k, v)`

Comment: What's wrong with using that dictionary as a `variable:value`  pairing in your code?

Comment: `if k in self.__dict__.keys()` => `if k in self.__dict__`

Comment: yeah, why everyone wants to define extra attributes?

Comment: @mgilson Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. MooingRawr, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: He means: you could `self.values = values`. Then you only have one more indirection, but at least you know which values come from `values` and there are no conflicts with existing attributes.

Comment: BTW you don't want to set class variables, you want to set instance variables.

Comment: must exist a dozen duplicates of that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) and [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class Foo(object):

    def load_values(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)


foo = Foo()
foo.load_values(egg='bacon', sausages='spam')
# or
foo.load_values(**{'egg': 'bacon', 'sausages': 'spam'})

print(foo.egg) # bacon
print(foo.sausages) # spam
```